# Is there any standard for the argument format of a program?

Tags: c++, c, standards, specifications

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{}
```

1. Is it possible that `argc` equals 0?
2. Must `argv[0]` be the executable file's name?
3. Is there any standard for these issues?

Comment: The relevant information is all in this answer to [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/15168).

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes.
2. Normally yes, it could also be empty, or some other identifying string, or even `NULL` (see my addendum). It's also possible to change `argv[0]` to something else from inside the program.
3. The C (and C++) specifications.

You also missed one: The last element in `argv` is always `NULL`, meaning `argv[argc]` will always be `NULL`.

---

In the C11 specification it's in §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup.

In the C++11 specification its §3.6.1 Main function.

Comment: 2. No; if it is not possible to determine the executable name, `argv[0]` may be a pointer to an empty string.  That said, it is more of a theoretical than practical statement.

Comment: And, on rereading the standards quoted in the duplicate, `argc` is permitted to be zero in both C and C++; I had forgotten that detail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was just about to update my answer before, but then had to go to a meeting. Updated now though. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No. Argv[0] don't have to exist, but if it does it is a program name, given it could be obtained.
3. I guess this is standard in C, Cpp. @JonathanLeffler linked a great answer.

Comment: Go check what the standards say in the duplicate question.  I'd forgotten about the possibility of `argc == 0` but the standards (both C and C++) explicitly allow it.  The value of `argv[0]` may be an empty string instead of the program name, assuming `argc > 0` — but only if it is impossible to tell the program name on the particular platform.  That is seldom a practical problem in hosted environments.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually quite surprising for me. You learn whole life :P

Comment: It surprised me, too.  As I said, I'd forgotten until I went to read once more...